# Hibernate @SelectBeforeUpdate(true) and @DynamicUpdate(true) not working with session.merge

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.7.Final and trying to update an object using the `session.merge(entity)` method. The entity is annotated with:

`@SelectBeforeUpdate(true)` and `@DynamicUpdate(true)`

However, I'm finding that the merge method overwrites original non-null fields (in the previously persisted entity) with null values from entity being merged - which I don't want. I thought `@DynamicUpdate` would only update non-null values.

The description of the merge method in the Hibernate docs is:

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return
>   it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become
>   associated with the session. This operation cascades to associated
>   instances if the association is mapped with cascade="merge"

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things i can think of quickly:

1. According to Hibernate doc, version/timestamp columns (@Version annotation if you use JPA) should be used as a optimistic locking strategy in order for Session.merge() to handle correctly modifications made to detached instances. Make sure to use this strategy.
2. @SelectBeforeUpdate and @DynamicUpdate are not inheritable so make sure the correct entities are annotated.